# How to get row count UNION, SUM MySql

Tags: mysql

I have this query and I want to get the row count, but I also get MySql error: ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(1) AS total FROM toys tiw 
                    LEFT JOIN item ti 
                    ON tiw.item_id = ti.id 
                    WHERE tiw.user_id='1785335'
                )
                UNION

                (

                    SELECT COUNT(1) as total 
                    FROM gadgets tfiw 
                    LEFT JOIN flair_store tfs 
                    ON tfiw.flair_id = tfs.id 
                    WHERE tfiw.user_id='1785335'
                ) t1
```

Comment: So, give *both* derived tables an alias (although I'm not sure that the second one needs one) - It's easy this MySQL stuff innit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to get the `sum()` of both totals, I believe you want to use:

```
SELECT SUM(total) 
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS total 
    FROM toys tiw 
    LEFT JOIN item ti 
        ON tiw.item_id = ti.id 
    WHERE tiw.user_id='1785335'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(1) as total 
    FROM gadgets tfiw 
    LEFT JOIN flair_store tfs 
        ON tfiw.flair_id = tfs.id 
    WHERE tfiw.user_id='1785335'
) d
```

Note I would also use `UNION ALL`.  The `UNION ALL` will return both values even if the total count is the same in both queries.  The `UNION` will remove duplicates.

As far as your error, you are missing an alias on one of your subqueries.